# How to implement a transparent Pane with non-transparent children?

Tags: javafx-2

How can i implement a transparent panel with non-transparent children in JavaFX 2?
The effect i want to achieve is for example applied to menus in Blender:

[image]

The menu-panel / window is transparent, but the text items are not transparent which leads to a pretty effect.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Set the background of your pane to a color with an alpha component.  You can use a stylesheet or an inline style for this.

For example, if your pane was named glass, then the following will give it a rounded, translucent cyan background:

```
glass.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 100, 100, 0.5); -fx-background-radius: 10;");
```

You could also accomplish similar effects using blends, stackpanes or groups of items with the [opacity](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#opacityProperty) set for items at the back of the stackpane or group.

Here is an executable example using the css background method.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TranslucentPane extends Application {
  @Override public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(
      new Image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b7/Idylls_of_the_King_3.jpg")
    );
    imageView.setFitHeight(300);
    imageView.setFitWidth(228);

    final Label label = new Label("The Once\nand\nFuture King");
    label.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: goldenrod; -fx-font: italic 20 \"serif\"; -fx-padding: 0 0 20 0; -fx-text-alignment: center");

    StackPane glass = new StackPane();
    StackPane.setAlignment(label, Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
    glass.getChildren().addAll(label);
    glass.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 100, 100, 0.5); -fx-background-radius: 10;");
    glass.setMaxWidth(imageView.getFitWidth() - 40);
    glass.setMaxHeight(imageView.getFitHeight() - 40);

    final StackPane layout = new StackPane();
    layout.getChildren().addAll(imageView, glass);
    layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: silver; -fx-padding: 10;");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
    stage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Sample program output:

[image: once and future]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! :)