# Translucent blurred background in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, uiblureffect

I want blurred translucent background effect in my JavaFx app like in the following image.

---

But I cannot find any satisfactory answer anywhere. 
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22960073/3947422) provides some workaround, it takes screenshot of background and sets it as background image. But the problem is, if background changes, it remain as it is.. (see [screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/58wntfqsz/))

[image: Blurred Translucent Background Effect]

So, I have two questions

1. If it is possible to have true blur effect (like aero effect in windows 7) in background of JavaFx application.
2. If yes, then how can I do it?

Comment: I haven't got a Windows system, to try it, but did you try the StageStyle.UNIFIED and does that work?  I think the behavior of UNIFIED is OS version specific, so I don't think it is not a generic solution for all systems.To test, you will need to take extra care that anything you put on the UNIFIED stage has no background (e.g. even a common stack pane usually has a background in JavaFX) and that the scene itself has no background color (which is not the default for a scene).

Comment: @jewelsea: It doesn't work. Not on Win7. Not even with Java 8u60 where it's supposed to be fixed. All I get is a black screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. For that to be possible, the JavaFX scene would need the information of everything below it and then render it blurred.

You could use a JNI approach as [demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22027247/java-setting-background-from-jar-and-making-it-transparent) with Swing, but seriously: don't. Since Aero is now dead even by Microsoft - who introduced it - I rather suggest you stick to something modern and take a different design approach.

Comment: Yes, Aero is "dead", but the "hint" used during window snapping (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/snap-your-windows-885a9b1e-a983-a3b1-16cd-c531795e6241) still can blur the stuff below itself.  I was trying to emulate that behavior recently and came to the same conclusion that JavaFX can't do it (which is not at all surprising, since probably that would not be possible on all other supported operating systems anyway).

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for info on whether 3D shapes could be translucent and came across your post. Have you seen this answer which shows how to make windows with translucent backgrounds? Perhaps that would help get you to something like what you are envisioning. [How to implement a transparent pane with non transparent children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717487/how-to-implement-a-transparent-pane-with-non-transparent-children)

Comment: Making the parent pane translucent can be done easily. But having the **translucent _blurred_** background thats what I was looking for.